# Алгоритмы; log n/n*log n

Tags: алгоритм

Кто-нибудь может привести пример алгоритма, работающего за `O(log) n` или `O(n*log n)`, и пояснить, где устанавливается сия зависимость?
Мне нужно написать алгоритм, узнающий, есть ли в массиве два одинаковых элемента, работающий за `O(n*log n)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O(log n) - поиск в двоичном дереве поиска, бинарный поиск.
O(n log n) - быстрая сортировка.

Comment: @a_gura а почему поиск в двоичном поиске дерева-O(log n)?

Comment: Потому что на каждом узле дерева мы будем смотреть половину от оставшегося.

Положим, в дереве 16 узлов.

На первом этапе возьмем половину дерева - 8 узлов, далее 4, далее 2, далее элемент будет найден. Итого 4 шага до поиска, 2^4 = 16, log(2)16 = 4

Comment: Если дерево не сбалансировано, то поиск может быть `O(n)`. Наивные реализации быстрой сортировки могут быть `O(n**2)`.